# Google sign in in Google assistant for dialog flow giving 500 internal server error?

Tags: google-signin, actions-on-google

[image: Simulator error]

Getting issue while linking google sign in with dialogflow. Showing strange error as shown in image. when opening debug url gives internal server error.

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#json

[image: 500 error]

Comment: @DiegoVieira - OP is using the Simulator, which is a development tool, so this does appear to be a development problem rather than a user problem.

Comment: Yes, I am working with simulator only. But it should work too as I have logged in through my account. So there is a user to fetch.